# Can i wake up my Android device through wifi?

Tags: android

I want to use my device like a camera in my house, and i want to enable/disable it times to times through Wi-Fi when needed! How can i do that? I know that when device in sleep mode, t disables wifi, but maybe there is some another feature to disable screen or something else.

Comment: I don't know if it helps but some apps use the sms to change behavior, I'm thinking of Avast! anti-theft which allows you to make the app change state or perform actions when receiving an specific sms from a specific person. I don't know exactly how it works but this may lead you to a solution !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didnt tried it so far but you would need to change Android-settings to let wifi turned on while the device is in sleep mode. So you have a connection running. Then you should create a background-service with a callback function. Everything what you need should be described here.

https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html